# Как связать Yii2 и React

Tags: reactjs, yii2

Возник такой вопрос, который покажется вам глупым.
Я создал API на Yii2 (basic), которое позволяет получать нужные данные из базы в json формате. Yii2 запускается на локальном сервере. Теперь я хочу создать, собственно, интерфейс на React и с помощью Ajax запросов обращаться к этим данным.
Что для этого нужно сделать?
Создать create-react-app в корневой папке проекта, и как-то сообщить yii об этом проекте? Или как-то по-другому это делается? Ответьте, пожалуйста, совсем новичок в этом.

И ещё, обязательно ли приложение будет SPA, или может быть и MPA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SPA или MPA решать исключительно вам. Зависит от самого проекта. А по поводу подключения к yii2 вам нужно сбилдить свой проект в чистый js. Для этого в scripts в package.json нужно иметь   "build": "react-scripts build", после запустить в терминале npm run build. Если же вы создавали React проект в WebStorm, то этот скрипт уже туда внесен. После того, как вы сбилдите js, в папке build будет index.html где будут подключен js. Далее нужно будет перенести index.html и директории с ресурсами js и css в ваш проект на yii. То есть в корневой роут внести эту эту верстку с этими ресурсами, как бы вы сделали имев обычную верстку.

Answer (score 0):

Для связки Yii2 как API и React как фронта, есть библиотека ReactYii2Essentials: https://github.com/BlackBes/react-yii2-essentials
Она сейчас в разработке, но уже позволяет в React воссоздать привычную для Yii2 иерархию, добавляет знакомые компоненты.
Так же у этой библиотеки, есть библиотека для самого yii2, онв добавляет gii генератор React CRUD, для быстрого старта, а так же базовые контроллеры и модели, чтобы API работал без костылей.
Рекомендую, попробуйте.